# IUpdatable<T> and IValueInsertable<T> from optional values?

Tags: linq2db

Is it possible to build something like this in Linq2DB? Currently I have a problem that `ITable<T>` is not assignable to either `IUpdatable<T>` or `IValueInsertable<T>`. Or maybe what I'm trying to achieve is not a good practice?

```cs
var optional1 = Optional<int>.None();
var optional2 = Optional<int>.Of(123);

var table = Database.MyTable; // ITable<MyRecord>
if (optional1.HasValue) table = table.Set(x => x.Optional1, optional1.Value);
if (optional2.HasValue) table = table.Set(x => x.Optional2, optional2.Value);

await table.UpdateAsync();
```

The same applies for `IValueInsertable`

```cs
var optional1 = Optional<int>.None();
var optional2 = Optional<int>.Of(123);

var table = Database.MyTable; // ITable<MyRecord>
if (optional1.HasValue) table = table.Value(x => x.Optional1, optional1.Value);
if (optional2.HasValue) table = table.Value(x => x.Optional2, optional2.Value);

await table.InsertAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AsUpdatable()`

```cs
var updatable = Database.MyTable.AsUpdatable(); 

if (optional1.HasValue) updatable = updatable.Set(x => x.Optional1, optional1.Value);
if (optional2.HasValue) updatable = updatable.Set(x => x.Optional2, optional2.Value);

await updatable.UpdateAsync();
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Should have played with intelli sense more. But what about IValueInsertable? There is no such method as `AsValueInsertable`?

Comment: there is a PR for `AsValueInsertable` https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/pull/3331